# django's manage.py dumpdata only dumping auth contrib's model data

Tags: python, django

I have my own app called `my_app` and is correctly installed via `INSTALLED_APPS` in my django settings module and is well tested with both devserver and test suites.

But when I try to dump model data of the `my_app` with `python manage.py dumpdata my_app`, it ends up with empty list while  `dumpdata` dumps `auth` contrib app's model data successfuly when I try `python manage.py dumpdata auth`.

What is wrong with my django commands?

Comment: Are you sure that `my_app` contains data? What happens if you append the `--all` option?

Comment: @rob yes, I can see database containing data via `python manage.py dbshell`. It still only dumps `auth` contrib app's data when I append `--all` option

Comment: Do you have more than one database in your `settings.py`?